# Where can I find more Desert Spores?

Tags: rage

I received the schematic for Apophis Fusion, which allows you increase your max health permanently by 11 points. You can craft this multiple times, but it appears one of the ingredients isn't real common: Desert Spore. I found 2 randomly in the Wasteland, and I believe I received 2 with the schematic, but I'm sure there may be more. Does anyone know the full list of places to find more Desert Spore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to find 14 of them ([source](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/rage/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-60558795&pid=942657&page=0)), it's for the Xbox 360 version, but that shouldn't make any difference.

- 2x from getting the recipe
- 2x by Joe's swamp
- 1x jump to mailbox (Mailbox challenge)
- 1x to the left of Bash TV
- 1x by Dr. Kvesir's mailbox
- 1x by the refuse "treasure" pile of the Outrigger Sewers (entrance located to the left of the parking poles leading to the Radio Tower)
- 1x by the Wellspring sewer entrance
- 1x by the northern tower that you have to resupply
- 1x by the Abandoned Distillery entrance (left side in the sunlight while heading towards the entrance)
- 1x to the left of Power Plant
- 1x at the sixth mailbox from the 3rd challenge
- 1x under the bridge leading to Subway Town, just past the sandbags that stop you from driving down there.

Comment: I thought they would just randomly respawn, that's rather disappointing

Answer (score 0):

there is a hidden merchant if you go to wellspring go into the outfitter after killing 300 mutants tou will see a small hatch on the floor proceed through the hatch and a merchant named berrys sells them for 37$

Comment: There is no hidden shop in the outfitters or anywhere for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to add my bit. Wellspring, in jackpot, After giving the ticket to Oasis. Sarah talks about the "Scorchers Mission". While on that mission, 2/3 through the pyramid structure left hand side, stairs leading down to the bottom. Go around the curve. 3 desert spores are there. I was able to bring my health up to 188.